# Why does this while loop output the same thing no matter what you input?

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop

I have a program that does three things. Asks you how many variables you wan't, ask you to input each variable, then stores it in a vector. I have put some code that checks if your input is correct, and if it isn't, re-loops the code asking for your variable. The problem I am having is that when you type anything in around the second variable, it asks you to try again infinitely.

For instance, if I typed these values into the input:

```
Variable amount: 5
Please input variable 1: 8
Please input variable 2: 8

 ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS
---------------------

Please input variable 2:
```

It would keep outputting `ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS` over and over again no matter what you typed. The code is down below, and if you have a better name for this question please let me know. (I'm not really sure what to call this)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int inputErrorMessage()
{
    cout << "\n ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS \n";
    cout << "--------------------- \n";

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Declare the variables, vectors, etc.
    int varNum = 1;
    int totVar = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    vector<int> userNums;
    double input = 0;
    string checktotVar = "";
    string checkInput = "";
    string sym = "";
    bool valid = false;
    stringstream sstotVar;
    stringstream ssinput;

    if (choice != 6) {

        while (!valid) {

            valid = true;

            // Ask user for how many variables they want then record it
            cout << "Variable amount: ";
            getline(cin, checktotVar);
            sstotVar << checktotVar;
            sstotVar >> totVar;

            if (sstotVar.fail() || totVar <= 0) {
                inputErrorMessage();
                valid = false;
                sstotVar.clear();
                sstotVar.ignore();
            }
        }

        valid = false;

        while (!valid) {

            valid = true;

            // Ask the user for each variable, then record it into the array
            for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i) {
                cout << "Please input variable " << varNum << ": ";
                getline(cin, checkInput);
                ssinput << checkInput;
                ssinput >> input;

                if (ssinput.fail()) {
                    inputErrorMessage();
                    valid = false;
                    ssinput.clear();
                    ssinput.ignore();
                }
                if (valid == true) {
                    userNums.push_back(input);
                    varNum++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to learn how to use your debugger. Please, it will help you in the future in addition to solving this issue

Comment: Also, note that you don't _have_ to declare all your variables at the very beginning of the function. Code is usually easier to read and understand when variables are declared close to where they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssinput >> input;
```

reads the one thing in `ssinput` right to the end of the stream while leaving the read valid. The next time around

```
ssinput << checkInput;
```

can't write into the stream because the stream hit the stream's end. That means the read also fails and

```
if (ssinput.fail()) {
```

enters the body of the `if` where the program clears the error

```
ssinput.clear();
```

and then promptly reads off the end of the stream with

```
ssinput.ignore();
```

causing the error all over again.

Quickest solution:

Recreate

```
stringstream ssinput;
```

on each loop iteration. So

```
stringstream sstotVar;
//stringstream ssinput; gone from here
```

and

```
    getline(cin, checkInput);
    stringstream ssinput(checkInput); // and now tighter scope recreated each loop.
    ssinput >> input;
```

Also by keeping the stream around without emptying it out it can get very., very big.

You can also simplify your logic around

```
while (!valid) {
```

and eliminate some repeated code by moving the read validation into it's own function

```
int getMeANumber(const std::string & message, int min)
```

that loops until it gets a number and then returns that number. For example:

```
int getMeANumber(const std::string & message, int min)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << message;
        string checktotVar;
        getline(cin, checktotVar);
        stringstream sstotVar(checktotVar);
        int totVar;
        sstotVar >> totVar;

        if (!sstotVar || totVar <= min)
        {
            inputErrorMessage();
        }
        else
        {
            return totVar;
        }
    }
}
```

Now `main` is this itty-bitty tiny lil' thing.

```
int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    vector<int> userNums;

    if (choice != 6)
    {
        int totVar = getMeANumber("Variable amount: ", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i)
        {
            stringstream varname;
            varname << "Please input variable " << i+1 << ": ";
            userNums.push_back(getMeANumber(varname.str(), numeric_limits<int>::min())); 
            // numeric_limits<int>::min requires #include <limits>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the issues with this code.

In this part:

```
if (valid == true) {
    userNums.push_back(input);
    varNum++;
}
```

you forgot to add an ssinput.clear(). This will reset the stream state (clear the error flags), otherwise you cannot use it again. That is why it stops working at the second input.

In addition, even though this works, you are pushing back a variable that you declared as double into a vector of ints. That is bound to cause issues if this was intended to store double variables, instead of truncating them and storing them as ints.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int inputErrorMessage()
{
    cout << "\n ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS \n";
    cout << "--------------------- \n";

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Declare the variables, vectors, etc.
    int varNum = 1;
    int totVar = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    vector<int> userNums;
    double input = 0;
    string checktotVar = "";
    string checkInput = "";
    string sym = "";
    bool valid = false;
    stringstream sstotVar;
    stringstream ssinput;

    if (choice != 6) {

        while (!valid) {

            valid = true;

            // Ask user for how many variables they want then record it
            cout << "Variable amount: ";
            getline(cin, checktotVar);
            sstotVar << checktotVar;
            sstotVar >> totVar;

            if (sstotVar.fail() || totVar <= 0) {
                inputErrorMessage();
                valid = false;
                sstotVar.clear();
                sstotVar.ignore();
            }
        }

        valid = false;

        while (!valid) {

            valid = true;

            // Ask the user for each variable, then record it into the array
            for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i) {
                cout << "Please input variable " << varNum << ": ";
                getline(cin, checkInput);
                ssinput << checkInput;
                ssinput >> input;

                if (ssinput.fail()) {
                    inputErrorMessage();
                    valid = false;

                }
                if (valid == true) {
                    userNums.push_back(input);
                    varNum++;
                }

                ssinput.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** You need to clear the stringstream on each iteration of the loop, otherwise you're not writing to an empty stream when you grab the next input from the user, which is what's causing the .fail() method to return true after the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Explanation added